# How to install brackets.io from the command line?

Tags: command-line, ppa

For some reason the gnome installer that handles .deb packages on my system is not working. I'm not concerned.

How would one install the Brackets.io program from the terminal?

Answer (score 21):

[Reference](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/install-brackets-in-ubuntu-via-ppa-open.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Answer (score 6):

## How to install *Brackets.Release.1.8.64-bit* on *ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64*:

1) Download *Brackets.Release.1.8.64-bit.deb*.

2) Download *libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb*.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb
```

3) Install **libgcrypt11**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb
```

4) Install **Brackets**:

[image: Brackets]

5) Run **Brackets**:

[image: Brackets]

Answer (score 0):

Brackets is a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install brackets --classic
```

Brackets is an open source editor for web design and development built on top of web technologies such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The project was created and is maintained by Adobe, and is released under an MIT License.

Comment: But for those of us who have never used `snapd` are there any benefits of this method versus a regular install like the other answers? I notice there is one less command line to copy and paste.

Comment: Installing brackets this way is a better package management policy because brackets is an Ubuntu package that's included in Ubuntu Software, and which can be easily installed without adding a PPA to the software sources.

Comment: snapd doesn't replace everything apt / apt-get does. Plus it "pushes" software onto the machine rather than giving user "pull" capacity. I think I'll just stick with apt and apt-get soley and continue to ignore snapd. Sorry.

Comment: You are more likely to have breaking compatibility issues with apt-get than with snapd. As of 5/2/2018 there remains a breaking incompatibility in Ubuntu 17.10+ (including 18.04 LTS) when using ```ppa:webupd8team/brackets```. As such, snapd remains the only working "installable" option.

Comment: And how do I launch it from the command line? `brackets` doesn't exist

Comment: Open brackets from the command line with `snap run brackets`